# Trouble installing and importing python packages

Tags: python-3.x, shell, pip

I've recently downloaded the python package colorama to use in a small project, I'm having trouble installing/importing it.

For a bit more background, I use MacOS and I have two versions of Python on my Mac; 2.7 which comes with the mac by default and 3.7 which I use to code. The package seems to have been successfully installed, as when I try to reinstall it I get the message below. However, when I try to import the colorama module using a script in python 3.7 it simply tells me it doesn't exist.

Have I installed it for the wrong version of Python? And, if so, is it possible to make 3.7 my default version of python to prevent this from happening again? Or am I wrong about this issue entirely?

```
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (0.4.1)
```

Comment: Use pip3 for install the dependency. As your log says you installed the dependency using pip for python 2.7 and you wanted to install it for python 3.7. You can change the environment variable that points to pip2.7 and point it to pip3 which is under the python3 installation folder

Comment: How did you install Python 3? You generally need to install the package separately for Py3.

Comment: First to address @AmiHollander; how do I go about changing the environment variable so it points to pip 3? I am pretty new to command line. @tripleee to be honest, I can't remember exactly, as I did it when I had first started out coding about 9 months ago. I believe I followed an online tutorial.

Comment: try this: `pip3 install colorama`

Comment: @PranavVoid that seemed to do the trick but now it's telling me I have to upgrade pip, the problem is when I try this I get the following:                                     
                                                                                                                         
`Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO'
Consider using the --user option or check the permissions.`